# My Smartphone should automatically tweet that I got up when I use it in morning. How can I achieve that?

Tags: automation, twitter

My Smartphone should automatically tweet that I got up when I use it in morning.

How can I setup my phone so that when I get up early in morning and first thing I do in morning is to swipe the screen, a tweet like

> I got up at 6 AM

is send?

Comment: OP: What you are asking for is bordering on something broad and similar to @bmdixon's answer below! There are plenty of tasker code out there, and anyway, why would you want your followers to know you got up at 6AM anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use [On {x}](https://www.onx.ms) for this. You should be able to configure it so that it sends a tweet the first time you unlock your phone each day. I've not used it much myself though so can't tell you exactly how.
Another possible option would be using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).

Comment: That sounds unwieldy, there are twitter apps out there that can facilitate scheduled tweets such as the one I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I interpreted the question as tweeting when he wakes up, not sending a tweet at a specific time. If he doesn't wake up till 7AM I presume he doesn't want to tweet till then.

Comment: Think the OP is asking a very broad and specific recommendation... at first I misinterpreted as silencing tweets, but no, have not heard of such a app, sure it can be done with likes of illama, tasker etc, but my feeling is the OP is *looking* for specific twitter app...

Answer (score 0):

As a user of [Tweetcaster Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.tweetcaster.premium&hl=en), which can do this for you!

There's a facility, to schedule tweets, at a designated user's time of their choice, as well into the future:

See screenshots below, notably **Post Later**:

[image]

[image]

But having said that, I normally ***do not*** answer to questions asking for *recommendations* as they are off-topic, please read the [FAQ].

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @t0mm13b: The OP was asking for an app that would **send** a tweet when they woke up, not supress incoming tweets until then.

Comment: See my edit! Sorry guys, I misinterpreted the OP's question